# Material Design Login with transition animation

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

I need to design something like this.
I do not understand how to animate the Floating action button like this.
[image]
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/android/meaningful-motion-with-shared-element-transition-and-circular-reveal-animation/